# How to determine time conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm assigning work shifts, and only one person is needed to be present.

A 'shift' has a time period, such as "9:30AM-4:30PM" and days that go with it such as "TWF" for Tuesday, Wednesday, Friday.

People need to be assigned shifts that don't overlap, so something like "8:30AM-5:00PM" on "TF" can't be assigned to someone else because it overlaps.

Is there a way to do this easily in Ruby on Rails, or am I just having to break this thing down into a string array, convert the time periods to ints, and work with it in a brute force manner?

Comment: When asking, we'd like to see evidence of the effort you've put into the problem. Most often this is the minimal code you've written that attempts to solve the problem. Without this it appears you're asking us to write code for you instead of you doing the research and putting in the effort and then asking us to help debug it. Please read "[ask]" including the links at the bottom. A quick search of "ruby time overlap" returns several hits.

Answer (score 1):

So you need to find all intervals with any overlap of a given interval. In other words, this would be (a) in the following picture:

[image]

You can define a query to find shifts by a time interval

```
def self.find_by_overlapping(shift_start, shift_end)
   inside_interval = where("start_time < ? AND end_time > ? OR start_time < ? AND end_time > ?", shift_start, shift_start, shift_end, shift_end) # Last 3 items in (a)

   outside_interval = where("start_time > ? AND end_time < ?", start_time, end_time) # First item in (a)

   inside_interval + outside_interval
end
```

With more effort you can clean up the SQL to return an ActiveRecord collection instead of an array if necessary.

Comment: Sorry but I'm a bit confused as to what this is doing?

Comment: Finds all shifts overlapping with `shift_start` and `shift_end`, which are both times.

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you shorten your code (use line breaks with %q{}) and used `BETWEEN`.

Comment: Doesn't it need to return anything like true or false? Having to use this with if statements along with other constraints on schedules.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite vague, but I'll make some assumptions and show you where that leads.

I've assumed the following:

- you have a set of `n` work schedules (e.g., one might be `["9:30","16:29", [2,3,5]]`, where `[2,3,5]` are day offsets for Tuesday, Wednesday and Friday)
- you want to assign each of `m` employees to zero or more work schedules
- exactly one person is to be working every hour of specified working hours for each day of the week

If no pair of work schedules is overlapping, every working hour of the week is included in exactly one work schedule, `m >= n` and each employee is to be assigned to at most one work schedule, the solution is simple: sequentially assign each of any `n` of the employees to any work schedule not already assigned.

I therefore assume that either some of the work schedules are overlapping or employees can be assigned to two or more non-overlapping schedules, the maximum number (perhaps two) to be specified.

Under these assumptions you have what's called an "NP-complete" optimization problem (which means, roughly, that the time to solve the problem increases exponentially with the "size" of the problem). You can formulate it as a *Integer Programming* problem and attempt to solve it with an IP optimization package, but you are not guaranteed to obtain a solution in any given amount of computing time. It could take years, or even light-years, depending on the size and nature of the IP problem.

Formulated as an IP problem the variables would be of the form x<sub>ij</sub>, which equals `1` if employee `i` is assigned to work schedule `j` and equals `0` otherwise. You would then have sets of linear constraints enforcing two requirements:

- each employee is to be assigned to no more that a given number of work schedules
- each hour of the week is to be included in exactly one assigned work schedule